# SQL code won't work in Excel VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, postgresql, excel

I am using Excel 2010 VBA and querying 3 tables from a PGSQL database

The following SQL code works perfect in MS ACCESS:

```
SELECT user.surname,user.forename,recall.recalldate,telephone.number
FROM (user INNER JOIN recall ON user.entity_id = recall.master_id) 
LEFT JOIN Telephone ON recall.master_id=Telephone.master_id
```

but doesn't seem to transfer to EXCEL VBA:

```
Dim RECALL As String
RECALL = "SELECT user.surname,user.forename,recall.recalldate,telephone.number " _
        & "FROM (user INNER JOIN recall ON user.entity_id = recall.master_id) " _
        & "LEFT JOIN Telephone ON recall.master_id=Telephone.master_id " _

Set rs = conn.Execute(RECALL)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
  .Refresh
End With
```

I get a runtime error: ...expected table source after FROM, got(

The user table links to the recall table using user.entity_id = recall.master_id and shows all recall records for users.
Then I need the telephone numbers for the matched users. Not all will have a tel number, but I need all recalls regardless of whether they have a tel number.

What is wrong with the SQL code in VBA?

Comment: You are comparing two different SQL dialects: MS Access ACE/Jet SQL and PostgreSQL. One difference is use of parentheses in joins. If PGSQL tables are linked in Access, you will run the ACE/Jet dialect. If using pass-through queries like in Excel, you use the direct connected PGSQL dialect. Had you run a pass-thru query in Access you would receive same error. Also `user` is a reserved word in both dialects. Either escape or rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a () after form try without

```
 SELECT user.surname,user.forename,recall.recalldate,telephone.number
 FROM  user INNER JOIN recall ON user.entity_id = recall.master_id
 LEFT JOIN Telephone ON recall.master_id=Telephone.master_id
```

Comment: This now shows runtime error: Preprocessor;relation "Telephone" does not exist; SQLSTATE 42P01;SOURSE_FILE src\backend\parser\parse_relations.c; COURSE_line 984; SOURCE_FUNCTION parserOpenTable

Comment: Check for Telephone or telephone  you have a lower case in select and upper case in JOIN .. otherwise you don't have a table with this name ..

Comment: Yep that's it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's probably different SQL for different databases.  Typically, the SQL is very similar, but there are always slight differences between different databases.

Take a look at this little utility in the link below when you have time.  That is very useful for converting SQL to VBA.  Give it a try, and see how you get along.

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-71.html